# Function calling a function within an object

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a Javascript object (the curly braces indicate it is so):

```
{
   a: function (something) {
      return something*2;
   },
   b: function () {
      var c = this.a(2);      //Does not work. Why?
      return c;
   }
}
```

What is the workaround to this?

Comment: This should work. How are you calling `b`?

Comment: The value of `this` is entirely dependent on how you are calling `b()` and cannot be answered otherwise.

Comment: Mathletics is correct. I was calling a from another function within b, which affects "this". The trick is to save "this" before entering that function within b.

Comment: Voted to close as `not a real question.`

Comment: Mathletics, I asked this question after searching around SO for an hour. I'm sure it will help someone else out.

Comment: Although you already selected an answer, it's not clear what the problem was, since you didn't say how you were calling the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It not work because when you access the method `b` it context isn't the instance from object that you made, it will try to search in the binded context or in `window` object.

```
var x = {
   a: function (something) {
      return something*2;
   },
   b: function () {
      var c = x.a(2);      //Does not work. Why?
      return c;
   }
}
```

This way you are using the `x` as context to access the method `a`.

Or you can use a `new` operator to create your object and the method as it prototype or direct method.

When you do it, the result will be:

```
var x = function() {
    return {
       a: function (something) {
          return something*2;
       },
       b: function () {
          var c = this.a(2);      //Does not work. Why?
          return c;
       }
    }
}
```

It will make you lose the `prototype` from `x`, when you make a new instance, but your code will work.

Example:

```
var y = new x();
console.log(y.b());
```

Comment: I thought `x =` was implied on the question. If not, how could the OP possibly be calling `b`?

Comment: yes, `x` is inside `b` method context. I did just put there for an example of use. This way you cant make it won't work using `x.b.apply(window);` for example.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, you were missing a coma after `a` declaration.

```
{
   a: function (something) {
      return something*2;
   }, // -> this one
   b: function () {
      var c = this.a(2);
      return c;
   }
}
```

If you call `b` the function should return `a(2)` which is 2*2=`4`

```
alert(p.b());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PNbXj/

Comment: Just a syntax error :) (I typed it manually and was wondering what was wrong, good find)